# Recursive FTP directory listing in shell/bash with a single session (using cURL or ftp)

Tags: bash, session, shell, ftp, curl

I am writing  a little shellscript that needs to go through all folders and files on an ftp server (recursively). So far everything works fine using cURL - but it's pretty slow, becuase cURL starts a new session for every command. So for 500 directories, cURL preforms 500 logins.

Does anybody know, whether I can stay logged in using cURL (this would be my favourite solution) or how I can use ftp with only one session in a shell script?

I know how to execute a set of ftp commands and retrieve the response, but for the recursive listing, it has to be a little more dynamic...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10):

The command is actually `ncftpls -R`. It will recursively list all the files in a ftp folder.

Comment: Have found that some FTP servers don't support this method.

Answer (score 6):

Just to summarize what others have said so far. If you are trying to write a portable shell script which works as batch file, then you need to use the lftp solution since [some FTP server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2007929) may not implement `ls -R`. Simply replace 123.456.789.100 with the actual IP adress of the ftp server in the following examples:

```
$ lftp -c "open 123.456.789.100 && find -l && exit" > listing.txt
```

See the `man` page of lftp, go to the `find` section:

> List files in the directory (current directory by default)
>   recursively.  This can help with servers lacking ls -R support. You
>   can redirect output of this command.

However if you have a way to figure out whether or not the remote ftp server implements proper support for `ls -lR`, then a much better (=faster) solution will be:

```
$ echo ls -lR | ftp 123.456.789.100 > listing.txt
```

Just for reference if I execute the first command (lftp+find) it takes 0m55.384s to retrieve the full listing, while if I execute the second one (ftp+ls-R), it takes 0m3.225s.

Answer (score 4):

If it's possible, try usign lftp script:

```
# lftp script "myscript.lftp"
open your-ftp-host
user username password
cd directory_with_subdirs_u_want_to_list
find
exit
```

Next thing u need is bash script to run this lftp command and write it to file:

```
#!/bin/bash
lftp -f myscript.lftp > myOutputFile
```

*myOutputFile* now contains the full dump of directories.

Comment: the `lftp` solution will actually works with Windows FTP server, even with support for `ls -R` removed: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2007929. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You could connect to the ftp server in a manner that it accepts commands from stdin and writes to stdout. Create two named pipes ("fifos", `man mkfifo`), redirect stdin and stdout of the ftp command each to one of them. Then you can write commands to the stdin-connected-fifo and read them (line-by-line with bash's `read` for example) from the stdout-fifo. Then use the results to see where you need to send another listing command (and print it or whatever you want to do)

In short: Not something bash scripting is suitable for :) (Until you find a tool that does what you want by itself of course)

Answer (score -1):

if you just want to create a listing of all files and folders, you can use `ssh` instead. Something like this (but check the documentation on correct usage)

```
$ ssh user@host "ls -R /path"
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. We don't know that he has shell access. This should be a comment.