# Get list of files from FTP server

Tags: bash, ftp

I'm trying to get a list of all the files we have on a server ( specifically every pdf file we have there ). I've tried using total commander and search for the files. It worked to some extent, as in, i got a list of every pdf we had there, but no way of exporting the results ( we have 100.000+ files there )

I've tried using a bash script to get the information, but i'm not very experienced with linux, and i don't really know what i'm doing.

My script looks like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
hostname="<host>"
ftp -i -nv $hostname << EOF
user <username> <password>
ls -R 
EOF
```

Running the above script i get

```
?Invalid command
501 Illegal PORT command
ftp: bind: Address already in use
221 Goodbye
```

Any help or pointing me on what to search would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to configure `ftp` to use the PASV (passive) mode for data transfers. This done with the `-p` switch.

I'm not sure if you will be able to do a recursive file listing with this ftp-client. `ls -R` in my case just gave the list of files and directories in the current working dir. Maybe [Recursive FTP directory listing in shell/bash with a single session (using cURL or ftp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614319/recursive-ftp-directory-listing-in-shell-bash-with-a-single-session-using-curl) will help you.

Answer (score 49):

With curl, this is handy
`curl ftp://yourftpserver/dir/ --user username:password`

Comment: FYI: `curl -l` returns just the names.

Comment: how do you script this to recurse?

Comment: I do not understand why most people are using username:password in their command, that's bad practice and can be history hjacked! At least use a (protected) file and use a substitution for it, e.g.: `curl ftp://yourftpserver/dir/ --user "$(cat .userpw)"`

Comment: Is there a human readable size output version?

Answer (score 7):

`ncftpls ftp://yourftpserver/dir/*.pdf`

Note that patterns such as `*.pdf`, etc. in the above command do work as expected.

For recursive, use `-R`. For more options, see `man ncftpls`.

`ncftpls` is provided by the `ncftp` package. For RHEL, this package is available in the `epel` repo.

Comment: Thank you @A-B-B, I didn't know about this utility. Now I can do this to get the name of the latest `coreutils` source code tarball: `ncftpls -x "-t" ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/coreutils*.xz|head -1`

Comment: A shame this does not use .netrc

Answer (score 7):

```
curl ftp://user:password@<ip>/path/
```

The last `/` is a must if it is a directory. This worked in curl version 7.29.0

Answer (score 4):

As mentionend in one of my comments, do not use user:password as plain text in your commands ever, otherwise you are running at risk of beeing history hjacked! Instead use at least a protected/restricted file with the username+password and substitute it in your command, e.g.:

```
ftp://yourftpserver/dir/ --user "$(cat .userpw)"
```

Whereas .userpw is your protected/restricted file with the example content: myusername:mypassword

Answer (score 3):

I have always run this FTP script in a linux system, after login `ls` command is submitted to a ftp connection(passive). List of files is written to a stdout stream. Script is inline in a sh script file.

```
#!/bin/sh

HOST=11.22.33.44
USER=myuser
PWD="mypwd"

ftp -p -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PWD
ls
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
curl --list-only ftp://user:password@ftp.adress/directory/JPG/
```

with curl request lists files